# AngularJS directive pass object error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I did a directive for AngularJS, this it inside a td of table, this is the code:

```
        <td ng-bind="order.Referencia"/>
        <directive order="order"></directive>
        </td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Company"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Poblacion"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Direccion"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Asegurado"></td>
        <td am-time-ago="order.ImportedOn"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Inside mi directive if i do order.file, order is undefined, but if i do this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders" ng-click="goToOrderDetails(order)">
        <td>
            {{order.file}}
            <directive order="order"></directive>
        </td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Referencia"/>
        </td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Company"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Poblacion"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Direccion"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.Asegurado"></td>
        <td am-time-ago="order.ImportedOn"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

order.field, order its defined...Why??

This is the directive code:

```
return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div></div>',
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    span.data("alert", {
                        importedOn: order.ImportedOn
                    });
    //do something
                },
                scope: {
                    order: '&'
                }
            };
```

Comment: try to get order from $scope ($scope.order....) in your directive

Comment: But i can take order in link? Why if i put the directive inside a new td works and otherwise not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive, change the scope binding description:

```
scope: {
    order: '='
}
```

in order to create a (two-way) binding to an object in the parent scope.